# Can I create an ASP.NET Core MVC Website using .NET 4.6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm a little confused when it comes to creating ASP.NET Core MVC applications. I know I can create an ASP.NET Core MVC application if I used the newly released .NET Core 1.0 framework.

I was wondering if I could create one using .NET 4.6 though. I created a new MVC application using .NET 4.6 but none of the new features, such as tag helpers, are available. Do I need to reference certain libraries? Is this even possible to do?

I should state that what I'm really after is being able to use the new Tag Helpers in a .NET 4.6 web application.

Comment: For Tag helpers, refer this - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers/

Comment: Please don't use "MVC 6". It's been renamed many months ago to "ASP.NET Core MVC" to distinguish it from the old ASP.NET MVC stacks and to imply that they are **not compatible** and a complete rewrite.

Comment: @Tseng Could you please a link to an MSDN source with the current nomenclature? Not that I don't believe you but I'd like to have it for reference.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/ It doesn't explicitly name MVC there, but MVC is one package of ASP.NET Core and versions of all packages were reset to 1.0.0 7 months ago. ASP.NET 5 and MVC6 just lead to confusion, making people believe MVC6 is an improved version of MVC5. This is not the case, it's complete rewrite which is not compatible with MVC5

Comment: Oh I see, it's called ASP.NET Core MVC now! https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating ASP.NET Core 1.0 app as MVC then target to .NET 4.6 framework. In this way you can create ASP.NET Core MVC application with .NET 4.6.

What your trying to do is build & compile core app for .NET 4.6 full framework

Comment: This would be the way to go.  Here are some supporting articles [link 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5) and [link 2](https://dusted.codes/understanding-aspnet-core-10-aka-aspnet-5-and-why-it-will-replace-classic-aspnet)

Comment: You definitely pointed me in the right direction. according to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/) article we can now choose .net framework or .net core framework when creating the project. I chose .net and the net461 monicker was added to the "frameworks" section of my projects.json file.

Comment: Is there anyway you can then run this without kestrel? but straight from IIS?

Comment: No you cannot run this without Kestrel, Even if you host it on IIS or nginx(linux) internal kestrel is that acts real web server