# How to create ASP.NET Core application on .Net Framework using VS 2017

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I've been doing some research to better understand the different between MVC 5 and MVC 6 and from what I understand MVC 6 is now a part of .NET Core.  However, I can still use .Net Core (which includes MVC 6) on the .Net Framework.  Is my understanding accurate and if so how do I do this in Visual Studio 2017.

Does the default MVC template in visual studio 2017 using .Net Framework 4.7.1 have MVC 6?  I ask because the template that is setup when you use MVC with the Core framework is slightly different and I can't tell.

Comment: If you replace the obsolete name of MVC 6 with ASP.NET Core as keyword, then any search engine can lead you to official articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework

Comment: Thanks, I was more interested in getting what is described here to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794738